# Elementary set theory proof. (symmetric differences and complements)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that: $A \Delta B = \overline{A} \Delta \overline{B}$

I think the way to do it is show both $A \Delta B \subseteq \overline{A} \Delta \overline{B}$ and also $\overline{A} \Delta \overline{B} \subseteq A \Delta B.$ But I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Write the definition of symmetric difference in basic set operations as union, intersection and compliment. Then use the De Morgan's laws to show the identity.

Comment: Complement (as in completion), not compliment.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\color{blue}{(1)}$:[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), and $\color{red}{(2)}$: The Equality $\color{red}{U\setminus V = U\cap V^c}$, we have:

$$  A^c\Delta B^c\stackrel{Def}= ( A^c\cup B^c)\setminus  (A^c\cap B^c)\stackrel{\color{blue}1}=(A\cap B)^c \setminus  (A\cup B)^c\stackrel{\color{red}2}=(A\cap B)^c \cap  (A\cup B)$$
$$\stackrel{\color{red}2}=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)=A\Delta B$$

Answer (score 2):

For all $x$ we have   $$x\in A\Delta B\iff$$ $$\iff [(x\in A\land x\not \in  B)\lor (x\not \in  A\land x\in B) ]\iff$$ $$\iff  [(x\not \in \bar A \land x\in \bar B)\lor (x\in \bar A\land x\not \in \bar B)]\iff$$ $$\iff x\in \bar A\Delta \bar B.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of showing both $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ is good. Now to use this approach we choose an element $x$ in the left set and show that it is then in the right set thus proving $\subseteq$, then to show $\supseteq$ we choose an element in the right set and show that it is in the left set.

**$A\Delta B \subseteq \bar A\Delta\bar B$**:

If $x\in A\Delta B$ then $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$. Thus $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in B\setminus A$. Assume that $x\in A\setminus B$ and note that by symmetry this case is similar as if $x\in B\setminus A$. 
Now if $x\in A\setminus B$ then $x\notin B$ i.e. $x\in \bar B$, however $x\in A$ implies $x\notin \bar A$. Thus we see that $x\in \bar B$ but $x\notin \bar A$, hence $x\in \bar B\setminus \bar A$, hence $x\in (\bar B\setminus \bar A)\cup (\bar A\setminus \bar B)$ i.e. $x\in \bar A\Delta \bar B$.

Now the other direction $A\Delta B \supseteq \bar A\Delta\bar B$ is very similar (some may even say it directly follows). We may even show it through a trick. Note that the above proof also show that if $X=\bar A$ and $Y = \bar B$ then $X\Delta Y \subseteq \bar X\Delta\bar Y$. However this is equivalent with $\bar A\Delta \bar B \subseteq \bar{\bar  A}\Delta\bar{\bar B}$, and since $\bar {\bar A}=A$ this show that $\bar A\Delta\bar B\subseteq A\Delta B $.